# VSCodeのターミナル上で、マウスを使わずに任意の位置の文字列を選択(コピー)する方法

Tags: vscode

VSCodeのターミナル上で出力結果を、マウスを使わずにキーボード入力のみで任意の位置の文字列を選択(コピー)する方法、もしくは、拡張があれば教えていただきたいです。
イメージは、Vimのビジュアルモードみたいな感じです。
tmuxやscreenを使わずに。

Answer (score 1):

Shift押しながら↑↓キーで選択、
Ctrl押しながらCキーでコピー

Windows上で、ですが